# Using one Applet to open another

Tags: java, applet, awt

I created a login applet that that I want to open another main applet once the user logins but I cant seems to get it to work right. I tried making an object of themain applet and then invoking it but that didnt work so then I tried creating another pane for the new applet and setting it inside of the login applet but that didnt work. Can someone tell me what im doing wrong?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class login extends Applet implements ActionListener{
    FundRaiserApplet secondApplet;
JLabel uname = new JLabel("Username");
JLabel pname = new JLabel("Password");
JTextField username = new JTextField(15);
JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField(15);
JButton login = new JButton("Login");
static final String USER = "identityone";
static final String PASS = "test";
JLabel status = new JLabel("");
JPanel fundraiserPanel;
public void init(){


setSize(250,200);


add(uname);

add(username);

add(pname);

add(password);

add(login);

add(status);
login.addActionListener(this);
setVisible(true);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if(e.getSource() == login){

    //status.setText("Password or Username is incorrect");
String user = username.getText();
String pass = password.getText();

try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Credentials;user=test;password=test");
     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
     Statement credR = conn.createStatement();
    String credentialSet = "INSERT INTO Credentials" +"( username, password)" + " VALUES('" + USER +"' , '" + PASS  +"' )";
    stmt.executeUpdate(credentialSet);



ResultSet ret = credR.executeQuery("SELECT username , password FROM Credentials");


while (ret.next()) {

   if(user.equals(ret.getString("username")) && pass.equals(ret.getString("password"))) {

       //didnt work
       FundRaiserApplet runme = new FundRaiserApplet();
       runme.init();

       JPanel container = new JPanel();
       container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));
       container.add(secondApplet); 
       add(container);
       secondApplet.init();
       secondApplet.start();
       secondApplet.setVisible(true);


       status.setText("Logged in");
   // this.dispose();


    //FundRaiserApplet.init();
   }else{

       status.setText("Wrong Username or Password");
   }
}
ret.close();
}     catch(Exception ex)
           {
           System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
           }

}
}


}
```

//MAIN CLASS BELOW////////////////////

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.applet.Applet;


public class FundRaiserApplet extends Applet {

    //database creation
   // static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    //static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost/";

     //end database creation


  ArrayList<String> resultsHold = new ArrayList<>();
    private JLabel DonorNamelabel;
    private JLabel AmountLabel;
    private JLabel charityName;
    private JLabel emptycell;
    static final String USER = "identityone";
    static final String PASS = "test";

    private JTextField donorNameTexfield;
    private JTextField Amounttextfield;

    private JTextField singletextfield;
    private JTextArea resultsscreen;
     public JButton seeAll;
    public JButton myExitButton;
    public JButton Enter;
     public JButton ClearButton;
    JPanel centerPanel;
    JPanel buttonPanel;
    JPanel textfieldPanel;
    JPanel myresultsPanel;
    JPanel results1Panel;
    //JPanel container = new JPanel();




    public void init() {

        setSize(400, 325);

        DonorInfo donor = new DonorInfo();
        String[] charityselections = { "Wounded Warrior Project","American Red Cross", "Doctors Without Borders","American Cancer Society","PETA"};
                final JComboBox<String> chairtycombo = new JComboBox<>(charityselections);

        chairtycombo.setVisible(true);




        //creating text fields, labels and buttons

       emptycell = new JLabel("");
       DonorNamelabel = new JLabel("Donor Name",10);
       AmountLabel = new JLabel("Pledge Amount",10);
       charityName = new JLabel ("Charity Name",10);
       donorNameTexfield = new JTextField(8);
       Amounttextfield = new JTextField(8);

       singletextfield = new JTextField(35);

       resultsscreen = new JTextArea(7, 35);
       final JScrollPane myScroll = new JScrollPane(resultsscreen);
       myExitButton = new JButton("Exit");
       myExitButton.setSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
       Enter = new JButton("Enter Info");
       Enter.setSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
       ClearButton= new JButton("Clear");
       ClearButton.setSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
       seeAll = new JButton("See All Results");
       seeAll.setSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
       seeAll.setMargin(new Insets(2, 0, 2, 0));



        //adding panels
        results1Panel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        textfieldPanel = new JPanel();
        myresultsPanel = new JPanel();

        //adding labels
        centerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 67, 0));
        centerPanel.add(DonorNamelabel);
        centerPanel.add(AmountLabel);
        centerPanel.add(charityName);


        // adding text fields
        textfieldPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 30, 3));
        textfieldPanel.add(donorNameTexfield);
        textfieldPanel.add(Amounttextfield);
        textfieldPanel.add(chairtycombo);


        //adding the buttons to the panel
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 5));
        buttonPanel.add(seeAll);
        buttonPanel.add(myExitButton);
        buttonPanel.add(Enter);
        buttonPanel.add(ClearButton);
        myresultsPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
        myresultsPanel.add(emptycell);
        myresultsPanel.add(myScroll);
        myresultsPanel.add(emptycell);
        myresultsPanel.add(emptycell);

        results1Panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 2));
        results1Panel.add(singletextfield);

        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        add(textfieldPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(results1Panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(myresultsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        //clear button action event listener

        ClearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

             @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

                donorNameTexfield.setText("");
                Amounttextfield.setText("");
                singletextfield.setText("");
                resultsscreen.setText("");
                resultsHold.clear();


            }
        });

        //end clear listener



        Enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            int counter=1;
             @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                singletextfield.setText("");
                double amountc = Double.parseDouble(Amounttextfield.getText());

                String charityselection = (String) chairtycombo.getSelectedItem();
                donor.setName(donorNameTexfield.getText());
                donor.setCharityname(charityselection);
                donor.setAmount(amountc);

                String name = donor.getName();
                Double amount = donor.getAmount();
                String charity = donor.getCharityName();

                String text ="Donor Name is:" +name +"\n"+"Pledge Amount: $" + amount + "\n"+"Charity Name: "+charity+"\n"+"-----------------------------------------------";

              //Ading the text variable into array
                      resultsHold.add(text);

              //displaying results in textarea

                      singletextfield.setText("Donor Name is:" +name +"  Pledge Amount: $" + amount + "..." + "Charity Name: "+charity);

                        try
               {
           // Create a connection to the database.
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Fundraiser;user=test;password=test");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
           String sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO Fundraiser" +"( NAME, PLEDGE_AMOUNT,CHARITY)" + " VALUES('" + name +"' , " + amount +" , '" + charity +"' )";


           stmt.executeUpdate(sqlStatement);

            System.out.println("Records Updated.");

// Close the connection.
           conn.close();
           System.out.println("Connection closed.");
        }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
           System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
           }
              // resetting text fields

                      donorNameTexfield.setText("");
                      Amounttextfield.setText("");
                      counter++;

               }


        });

        //event listeners
        myExitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //exit program
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

            seeAll.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {

                  try{
                 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Fundraiser;user=test;password=test");

                 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

                  String sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM Fundraiser";




                 ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStatement);


                 while (result.next())
           {

               resultsscreen.append("Pledge Name: " + result.getString("NAME") + "\n"+
                                 "Amount Given: "+result.getDouble("PLEDGE_AMOUNT") +"\n"+
                                 "Donor Charity: " + result.getString("CHARITY")+"\n"+ "........................."+ "\n");


          }

           // Close the connection.
           conn.close();


                 }     catch(Exception ex)
           {
           System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
           }
                 //resultsscreen.append(text.toString());
        });   

    }
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //database initialization

    Connection conn = null;
    Connection conn2 = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    Statement start = null;
   try{
      //downloaded driver "mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar" and added into project library
       //downloaded "derbyclient.jar" and added to library
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();

      //connection time!
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");

      //if a folder already exist in "C:\Users\User\.netbeans-derby" called "Fundraiser" then delete it or it will throw an exception
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Fundraiser;create=true;user=test;password=test");
      conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Credentials;create=true;user=test;password=test");  
      //Create database
      System.out.println("Fundraiser Database Created!");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      start = conn2.createStatement();

      try{
      String sql1 = "DROP TABLE Fundraiser";
      String dropcreds = "DROP TABLE Credentials";

      stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);
      System.out.println("Fundraiser Table Deleted...");
      start.executeUpdate(dropcreds);

      System.out.println("Credentials Table Deleted...");
      }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("No Table to Delete...");}


      String sql = "CREATE TABLE Fundraiser" +
"(NAME VARCHAR(255), " +
" PLEDGE_AMOUNT DOUBLE, " +
" CHARITY VARCHAR(255) )";

String sql2 = "CREATE TABLE Credentials" +
"(username VARCHAR(255), " +
" password VARCHAR(255) )";


      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
       System.out.println("Fundraiser Table created successfully...");
      start.executeUpdate(sql2);

      System.out.println("Credential Table Created successfully...");


   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){

      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{

      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException my2){
          System.out.println(my2);
      }
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException my){
         my.printStackTrace();
      }
   }//end try

  FundRaiserApplet applet = new FundRaiserApplet();
        applet.init();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Identity One");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( applet );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );

        applet.start();

//login.main(args);

   }


public void ShowWindow() {

        FundRaiserApplet applet = new FundRaiserApplet();
        applet.init();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Program");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( applet );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );

        applet.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Code the functionality in panels, and use a `CardLayout` to flip between them.  Either that or pop the 'log in panel' in a `JOptionPane`  But.. 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Comment: One applet can't open another one. You can have multiple applets on the same HTML page, or you can use a CardLayout as @AndrewThompson suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use javascript to open the second applet in the web page.